# How to monitor FTP traffic?

Tags: ftp

My FTP client is connected to a remote server and displays upload traffic. But I can't see this traffic anywhere: both Fiddler and Ressourcemonitor don't display any FTP connection and traffic.

How can I see FTP traffic with monitoring tools?

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? Is the FTP connection working and you just want to monitor it?

Comment: Im not sure whether it is working correctly and want to monitor it

Comment: If the server has not sent an error back, why assume it may not have worked? The only way you could tell for sure is access to the server and perhaps run some sort of crc check both ends. Regardless, no one _really_ uses ftp any more due to the security risks. Lastly, you do realise that ftp uses ports 20 & 21

Comment: Fiddler is for HTTP, not FTP. Resource Monitor absolutely will show you the underlying TCP connections, but that’s not helpful information. The best “monitoring tool” is your FTP client. Just look at its log window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running Wireshark with the `ftp || ftp-data` filter shows the Request/Response traffic to/from the FTP server